# I am getting Error with react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am coverting my react class based component to react typescript.But I am getting error which I am unbale to solve

Below is code for react class based component
Grid.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import './Grid.scss';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

type MyProps = {
    className:any
    rowData:any
    columns:any
    updateRecord:any
    onDeleteRecord:any
    onCellClicked: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    
};

type MyState = {
};

export default class Grid extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props:MyProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }


    onCellClicked = (params) => 
    {
        // Handle click event for action cells
        if (params.column.colId === "Action" && params.event.target.dataset.action) 
        {
            let action = params.event.target.dataset.action;

            if (action === "update") 
            {
                this.props.updateRecord(params.node.data.id, params.node.data.name, params.node.data.description, params.node.data.created, params.node.data.created_By);
            }

            if (action === "delete") {
                this.props.onDeleteRecord(params.node.data)

            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const gridOptions = {
            getRowStyle: params => {
                if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 1) {
                    return { background: '#ebebeb73' };
                }
            },
        };

        
        return (
            <div className={["sct-grid", this.props.className, this.props.noHoverEffect && "nohover"].filter(Boolean).join(" ")}>
                <AgGridReact gridOptions={gridOptions}
                    alignedGrid="true"
                    suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns={true}
                    pagination={true}
                    paginationPageSize={7}
                    rowData={this.getitems()}
                    onRowEditingStopped={this.onRowEditingStopped}
                    onRowEditingStarted={this.onRowEditingStarted}
                    onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked}
                    editType="fullRow"
                    suppressClickEdit={true}
                    enableRangeSelection={true}
                    columnDefs={this.props.columns}

                >

                    {/* { this.getColumns()}*/}

                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        );
    }

    getitems() {
        return this.props.rowData;
    }



    getColumns() {
        var listOfColumns = [];
        if (this.props.columns) {
            this.props.columns.forEach(column => {
                listOfColumns.push(<AgGridColumn key={column} minWidth="80" maxWidth="120" field={column.field} sortable={column.sortable} filter={column.filter}></AgGridColumn>);
            });
        }
        return listOfColumns;
    };
};
```

I have tried everything for params like React.ChangeEvent or MOUSEEvent..But nothing is working.[image].So could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't know about the type of the params object.

you need to define the type explicitly

```
// use any or define type of the params object 
// 
onCellClicked = (params: any) => 
    {
        // Handle click event for action cells
        if (params.column.colId === "Action" && params.event.target.dataset.action) 
        {
            let action = params.event.target.dataset.action;
```

Comment: I would avoid assigning this to `any` when it's possible to assign it to the correct type.

Comment: Using any isn't really defining types explicitly. It's more like: I don't want to specify a type here.

Comment: @Evert i haven't specified that you should use `any` only . op can make choice of his own on what interface he has to use.

Comment: As of now  I have defined like params:any and now it is showing not error..But other error comes

Comment: Assigning as `any` is just side-stepping the problem and is likely to be the reason you have other errors. Assign the correct type and you'll quickly notice that a bunch of properties you're trying to use do not exist or are possibly undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it to the `CellClickedEvent` which is provided by the [ag-grid-community](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-community). You may have to install `ag-grid-community` with NPM or Yarn:

```
import { CellClickedEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

```
onCellClicked = (params: CellClickedEvent) =>
```

They have a [reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-events) for their events too.